# how to move committed-but-unpushed changes to another branch?

Tags: git

I've got some unpushed git commits in my child of our master branch.  I did a rebase to a feature branch, and successfully merged the few conflicts that resulted, but I didn't realize that rebase wouldn't leave me on the feature branch.  If I now git checkout the feature branch, it will presumably overwrite my committed changes in my working tree, leaving them in some kind of limbo.  I could "git checkout -m", but that apparently is only for merging uncommitted local changes.  How can I get onto the feature branch and keep my unpushed-but-committed changes that I currently have under the master branch (without pushing them to the master branch)?  Should I have used git rebase -onto?  If so, what should I do now that I've rebased without -onto?

Comment: Not a dupe. It's a very different problem with changes that are already committed, not to mention have gone through an incorrect rebase.

Answer (score 9):

You can do it like this:

1. `git checkout branch` to checkout the feature branch.
2. `git reset --hard master` to move the branch to be the same commit as `master` right now. By doing this, you lose all commits that are in the branch. Because of your rebase, all those commits should have copies on `master`, so you shouldn't actually lose anything.
3. `git checkout master` to checkout `master`.
4. `git reset --hard origin/master` to reset `master` to the state that is on the `origin` repo. This assumes you didn't have any unpushed changes to `master`. If you do, replace `origin/master` with the commit id you want to reset to.

Comment: "you lose all commits that are in the branch..."  I don't follow this part. My goal is to keep my unpushed commits by moving them to the feature branch.

"this assumes you didn't have any unpushed changes to master".  Again, unpushed commits are the whole reason why I'm asking my question.

Comment: I see that wat I want to do is described in the git-reset man page under "Undo a commit, making it a topic branch".

Comment: The git man page mentioned by BrianHoltz is here: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset/2.0.0#_examples

Comment: Small note: for my case I wanted to move the commits to a _new_ branch after starting work on master and accidentally committing there. For this you can use `git checkout -b new-branch` as step 1 (adding the `-b` flag to `git checkout` creates a new branch) and skip step 2 (since you are already on the same commit as master).

Answer (score 4):

First to restate your situation to make sure I understood correctly.  You made a few commits on `master` and wanted to move them to `feature`, so you ran `git rebase feature`? First, you want to undo that.  Assuming you still have `master` checked out, and haven't done any rebases since, run `git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD` to undo the rebase.

Now, for the proper way to move your commits over to the `feature` branch.  Make and checkout a temporary branch so you don't mess up `master`:

```
git checkout -b temp
```

Now rebase all the changes made since the last commit on `origin/master`onto`feature`:

```
git rebase --onto feature origin/master
```

That moves the `temp` branch as if it was branched from `feature`.  Now to merge the changes onto `feature`, do:

```
git checkout feature
git merge temp
git branch -d temp
```

It will be a fast-forward merge since you just rebased.